# Hook In Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook

I modify wp_hash_password and wp_check_password with my own encryption password, I want to use hook now. This is to make sure when my wordpress update the latest version, my wp_hash_password and wp_check_password in pluggable.php still is my own password encryption, the hook should add at where? Look on Internet, some say put in user.php and some say put in function.php in theme. If who know, please tell me the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins are loaded first, then pluggable.php and then lastly the theme.  Subsequently, you need to create a plugin and place your pluggable functions code in there otherwise your custom code won't be loaded. Create a file called `custom_wp_password_override.php` or whatever you want to label it and place it in your plugin's folder adding in your own custom function code.  You should never update core files such as user.php as this will be overwritten when you upgrade WordPress.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom WordPress Passwords
Plugin URI: http://localhost
Description: Override wordpress pluggable password functions.
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Your Name
Author URI: http://locahost
Text Domain: custom-wp-passwords
*/

if ( !function_exists('wp_check_password') ) :
    function wp_check_password($password, $hash, $user_id = '') {
        // Your custom code in here
    }
endif;

if ( !function_exists('wp_hash_password') ) :
    function wp_hash_password($password) {
        // Your custom code here
    }
endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing I know when into WordPress development is not to edit any files in two folders: wp-include and wp-admin. Or you will lose all your edit when update WordPress to the newer version.

Back to your question, if you think you will not change the theme in the future, put your code in child theme's functions.php. Yeah, child theme will not affect when you update your parent theme.

And I think, **the best solution for you** is creating a simple WordPress plugin, put your code in, and activate that plugin. So your encryption will not lose when you update WordPress core/theme/other plugins even.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WP Custom Plugins
Plugin URI:  http://link to your plugin homepage
Description: This plugin changes WordPress hashing password encryption.
Version:     1.0
Author:      Someone
Author URI:  http://link to your website
License:     GPL2 etc
License URI: https://link to your plugin license


/* Your code goes below here */
```

Comment: for second point, mean add my hash_password and check_password at there?

Comment: @MollyMolly If you want to know how to create a WordPress plugin, see it here: http://www.wpexplorer.com/writing-simple-wordpress-plugin/. And yes, just simple put your code in plugin file. I will update my answer to clarify it.

Comment: I done already, thank for ur help, but Andrew Schultz solution more close with my answer, so , i click his solution.